# Where does the MVC Controller User Property pull its information from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the logged in Active Directory user by using the User property on an MVC controller. I then use this name of that user to display data from a database.

```
userID = User.Identity.Name;
```

I frequently get reports from users saying they see someone else's data. They also report that if they close their browser and go back in, they see the correct data. I added some code to the controller to log the value coming from User.Identity.Name. Sure enough, it appears that User.Identity.Name is returning the incorrect user at seemingly random times.

I am not sure why this is happening. Is it possible IIS is caching user credentials after it serves a request, then passes it on with the next request?

I have seen references to the following KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946358 ,however when I got there from a question asking about System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.user. Do that and User property on the controller grab their information from the same place?

I am really not sure where to start troubleshooting this problem, as it appears to be a configuration issue vs. a code issue. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using static classes anywhere to hold this data?

Comment: The identities are stored either in Thread.CurrentPrincipal or HttpContext.Current.User. A controller will use the last one, the KB you referenced will use Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Your problem is most likely related to what @Charleh said

Comment: @Charleh Thanks for the response. I have double checked for static variables/methods/classes with respect to holding the UserID. Unfortunately static classes are not being used anywhere. The UserID is a private variable in a (non-static)Controller, and it is set within a private non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

Taken straight from the `Controller` class metadata in .NET:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets the user security information for the current HTTP request.
//
// Returns:
//     The user security information for the current HTTP request.
public IPrincipal User { get; }
```

I'm fairly certain that the `get` definition pulls the `User` object from the current `HttpContext`.